# Question regarding change of basis

Tags: matrices

Given two basis {$\textbf{e}_a$} and {$\textbf{e}_{a'}$}, we can have
$$\textbf{e}_a = R^{b'}_a\textbf{e}_{b'}$$
$$\textbf{e}_{a'} = R^{b}_{a'}\textbf{e}_{b}$$

Substituting the second equation into the first we get
$$\textbf{e}_a = R^{b'}_aR^{c}_{b'}\textbf{e}_{c}$$
from which we deduce that
$$R^{b'}_aR^{c}_{b'}=\delta^c_a$$
The problem comes when I was told that the above equation can also be expressed in matrix form as
$$[R^{b'}_a][R^{b}_{a'}]=I$$
where the lower indices are the rows and upper indices the columns. I could not get the indices of $[R^{b}_{a'}]$ sorted out from the previous equation. Any help?

Comment: Note that $(I)_{i,j} = \delta_{ij}$ (in standard notation, your $\delta_a^c$ probably means $\delta_{ac}$)

Answer (score 0):

Note: $$[R^{b}_{a'}]=[\delta^a_bR^{b}_{a'}]=[R^{a}_{a'}]$$

Comment: How did you get $[R^{b}_{a'}]=[\delta^a_bR^{b}_{a'}]$? Even if I do make the above changes, how do I show that the equation with the kronecker delta and the one with identity are equivalent?